# How do i get the correct file name number according to where i moved the trackBar1 value?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have trackBar1 in form1 constructor i'm getting all the files from a directory:

```
DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(radar_images_download_directory);
file_info_mouse_wheel = dir1.GetFiles("*.gif");
```

Then i set the trackBar1 maximum minimum and start value also in the constructor:

```
trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
trackBar1.Maximum = file_info_mouse_wheel.Length - 1;
trackBar1.Value = file_info_mouse_wheel.Length - 1;
```

In this case i have 2635 files in file_info_mouse_wheel

Then i have a button click event:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            if (b.Text == "Confirm Start")
            {
                mtp1Start = trackBar1.Value;

                label12.Text = mtp1Start.ToString();
                button1.Enabled = false;
                b.Text = "Confirm End";
            }
            else
            {
                mtp1End = trackBar1.Value;
                if (mtp1End == mtp1Start)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Both values start and end can't be the same");
                    b.Text = "Confirm End";
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mtp1End > mtp1Start)
                    {
                        mtp1End = trackBar1.Value;
                        label14.Text = mtp1End.ToString();
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                        b.Text = "Confirm Start";
                    }
                }

                if (mtp1End < mtp1Start)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("End can't be smaller then start");
                    b.Text = "Confirm End";
                    button1.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mtp1End != mtp1Start)
                    {
                        mtp1End = trackBar1.Value;
                        label14.Text = mtp1End.ToString();
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                        b.Text = "Confirm Start";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that when i move the trackBar value to for example value of 2623 it's file number 003642.gif

And i assign to the mp1Start and mp1End.

Then later i'm doing a loop starting from mp1Start to the mp1End:

```
for (int i = mtpStart; i < mtpEnd; i++)
```

And inside the loop i'm building the file name according to the values in mp1Start and mp1End:

```
String FileName = radar_images_download_directory + "\\radar" + i.ToString("D6") + ".Gif";
```

But i'm not getting the correct files. 
Since if mp1Start for example the value is 2623 i will get file number 2623 but in fact on trackBar1.Value 2623 it's file 003642.gif

And the file that i should build and get in FileName is 003642.gif and not 002623.gif

How can i correct this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't build the filename at all...

when you read your directory contents, create an array of filenames, maybe sort them as needed, and pass this array to a variable for later use ...

when you need to get filenames, get them from the array